# How to deal with date field while modeling in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

My df contains data for 2 years history of user values, coming from different countries.

```
value user country pdt       date
1     a     aa     xx    01/01/2000
1.3   a     aa     xz    02/01/2000
2     b     aa     xx    01/01/2000
4     c     bb     yx    01/01/2000
5.9   c     bb     xx    03/01/2000
2     d     cc     yy    01/02/2000
```

I want to predict the value *per user*.

In this minimal model I can use `lubridate` to extract a variety of date fields (`dayoftheweek`, `month`, `is_weekend` and so on).

I want to estimate the simplest linear model -  and I am taking out the `user` field as redundant:

```
value = a*country + b*pdt + c*date + err
```

My question is:

- How should I deal with `date` field in the regressors? Should I just use the extracted fields (`dayoftheweek`, `month`, `is_weekend` and so on) as regressors and leave out the original `date` column formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`?

It is not clear to me the point where I could model it as a multivariate regression problem or a time series problem (that it is be able to predict value *per user* and not general time series sale *per country* or *per product*).

When I roughly check the assumptions on the simplest model, using `gvlma` package:

```
library(gvlma)
mod <- lm(value ~ date, data=df)
gvlma(mod)
```

None of the assumtions are met (no linear relationship for X,Y; relationship skewed, the distribution is kurtotic and residuals are heteroscedastic).

```
                               Value p-value                   Decision
Global Stat        2408258247927.113  0.0000 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Skewness               246069225.832  0.0000 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Kurtosis           2408012123151.410  0.0000 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Link Function                  1.274  0.2591    Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity         55548.598  0.0000 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
```

How should I proceed? Should I transform somehow the date? Should I add trend/splines? Should I move to a glm/random forest model to account for non-linearity? Or a time series?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Since this is time-series data, I think you should (at least) use a method which would deal with the autocorrelation.

Comment: Hello! Durbin-Watson on the minimal model `lm=(value ~ days_since_origin, data=df)` (I am not using date but the scaled version since `min(df$date)` says that the residuals are autocorrelated. What I could do is: Add lag1 of residual as an X variable to the original model. This leads to the ACF plot to look ok and the DW test to have a p-value > 0.05 @T.E.G.

Comment: But my doubt is more: how to predict value *per user* in a time series set-up? Wouldn't the time series forecast be on the overall amount of value - let's say - daily? I am confused @T.E.G.